# Prototype for Multiple functions in one declaration

Tags: c++, prototype

Quick newbie question: how do I read the block of code below (it comes from the textbook *Physically Based Rendering* Section 12.1)? It's something that I've never seen before. Is it the prototype for three different functions of class Light (i.e. Light::nSamples, Light::LightToWorld, and Light::WorldToLight)?

```
(Light Interface) ≡                                                                                  606
Light(const Transform &l2w, int ns = 1)
    : nSamples(max(1, ns)), LightToWorld(l2w),
       WorldToLight(Inverse(l2w)) {
     (Warn if light has transformation with scale)
}
```

Comment: That's not valid C++ code. That said, I guess you are confused about the syntax on an initialisation list. Please read a C++ tutorial, it's explained there.

Comment: It comes from a textbook; so I figure they mean to use psuedocode. I I assume that they are defining this category _Light Interface_ to be composed of three different functions: nSamples, LightToWorld, and WorldToLight.

Comment: Those are not functions, but member variables or base classes, instantiated at construction time.

Comment: The syntax of pseudocode is meaningless because it doesn't have to be compiled. And no, your assumption is probably wrong. Did you make that assumption before or after reading a C++ tutorial or researching the term I gave you?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of pseudo code mixed with c++ syntax.

```
(Light Interface) ≡
```

It means nothing, probably a comment. You even have some Unicode chars there.

The rest looks like a bad definition of a constructor of  `class Light`

```
Light(const Transform &l2w, int ns = 1)
```

This would be the constructor with it's arguments, it's has an error as it should be `Light::Light(const Transform &l2w, int ns = 1)`

```
    : nSamples(max(1, ns)), LightToWorld(l2w),
       WorldToLight(Inverse(l2w))
```

This is instantiation of member variables and base classes.

```
{
     (Warn if light has transformation with scale)
}
```

Here would go the constructor code, instead of another weird pseudocode comment.

Comment: Just so I know, why is it bad to have Unicode characters in a C++ statement?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason you've never seen it before. This is nonsense:

```
(Light Interface) =
```

The rest, if it was written

```
Light::Light(const Transform & l2w, int ns - 1)
...
```

would be the definition of a constructor.

I'm not familiar with the book this comes from, but I'm skeptical that this sort of informality will actually be helpful.

Comment: In my mind it's just psuedocode. I think it means.

"(Light Interface) ≡ " means that the catetory _Light Interface_ is defined to be... and the rest of it would just be a constructor.